# How to send json data from node js to html page

Tags: node.js

I have already get a serier of json data from facebook using node js express. Now I want to send the data to a html page. But I have no idea how to send the data and encode the data in html.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use Express in node.js, here is the way to send json object as response:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});
```

Then in JS on your html page html, if you use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/test',
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Feel free to experiment with stuff, as well use Dev Tools in Chrome, experimentation - helps a lot to understand what and how it works.

Comment: TIL `res.json()` - that's just saved me a load of effort with `JSON.stringify` all over the place

Comment: You could do res.send() as well, as far as I am concern, latest express will add application/json Content-Type if you try to send object.
It is up to jQuery to parse it properly. Although if Content-Type is not json but you still sure it will be always json, then you can force it in jQuery by adding `dataType: 'json'` in parameters in `$.ajax({ ..`

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info (although admittedly I feel like I should've just read the docs and saved you the time `;)`)

Comment: @JianyuanMa you are welcome. Please use accept features and rating system of StackOverflow, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Finally, this is what I was looking for ... well working

Answer (score 0):

Use [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json). For instance:

```
function(req,res) {
  res.json({ user: 'tobi' })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Heroku's example tutorial. I think it does exactly what you are asking for in terms of JSON encoding + throws in Web Sockets. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Comment: It is better to give a brief explanation, and provide the link for reference of details. Link-only answers may become invalid if the linked page changes.