# How to take JSON Objects and put them in HTML

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, dashboard

I want to put information about user (information from discord, like username and discriminator) in website. When authorized, all data in formal JSON. Here's code.

````
  "/callback",
  passport.authenticate("discord", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/dashboard");
  } // auth success
);
app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});
app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, function(req, res) {
  //console.log(req.user)
  res.json(req.user);
});```
````

Comment: So, how to take info, and put it in HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send json data from node js to html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365039/how-to-send-json-data-from-node-js-to-html-page)